# reading inputs from file up to specific character cpp

Tags: c++, file, input, visual-c++, char

Im tryin to read input.txt include string (move_back; turn_around[radius];).

I should allocate string command and attribute like;

up to ";" is command // move_back; is a command

between "[" and "]" is attribute // [radius] is and attribute

ı write these two program for this but ı need to combine in one program. And also ı dont know how can ı read between "[" "]" ı think ı shoul start reading at "[", finish reading at sight "]" char. ı dont know how to write this code and combine all these.

input.txt

move_back;

turn_around[radius];

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

// reading input from file line by line
void read() {
    ifstream file;
    file.open("input.txt");
    string line;
    while (getline(file, line)) {
        cout << line << endl;
    }
    file.close();
}



 #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    #include <fstream>
    using namespace std;


   int main()
{
     // to find commands reading up to ";"
        string s = "move_back; turn_around [radius];move_back [time];";
        string delimiter = ";";
        vector<string> commands;
        int pos = -1;
        while (s.find(delimiter) != -1) {
            pos = s.find(delimiter);
            commands.push_back(s.substr(0, pos));
            s = s.substr(pos + delimiter.length());
        }
    
        for (int i = 0; i < commands.size(); i++) {
            if (isspace(commands[i].at(0)))
                commands[i] = commands[i].substr(1);
        }
        
}
```

Comment: Your question isn't quite clear.   You should write some code that attempts to do what you want and then ask a question with a specific question as to what doesn't work.  Stylistic questions aren't good questions for stack overflow.   Basically we won't do your homework, but if you run into a specific problem, we'll help you get past it.  If your code has an input file, make sure you post that file as part of the program (or better yet, just hard code the data into a string in your question - since reading the file isn't your problem)

Comment: Hi it is not homework it is a part of my practice to solve some big hackerrank problems. Im trying to be clear 
 as ı can do and going to work about that. thanks for your opinion

Comment: I would consider it more "advice on how to get your problem answered" than an "opinion".   You'll notice you have no responses.   Fixing your question would likely help that.  I'll check back in in a few hours and see what you've done and if you've improved your question to an [mcve] then I'll try to answer it.